# awk sum every 4th number - field

Tags: linux, awk

So my input file is:

```
1;a;b;2;c;d;3;e;f;4;g;h;5 
1;a;b;2;c;d;9;e;f;101;g;h;9 
3;a;b;1;c;d;3;e;f;10;g;h;5
```

I want to sum the numbers then write it to a file (so i need every `4th` field).

I tried many sum examples on the net but i didnt found answer for my problem.

My ouput file should looks:

```
159
```

Thanks!

Update:

```
a;b;**2**;c;d;g
3;e;**3**;s;g;k
h;5;**2**;d;d;l
```

The problem is the same.

I want to sum the 3th numbers (But in the line it is 3th).

So `2+3+2`.

Output: `7`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you want to print every 3rd field, not every 4th. The following code loops through all fields, suming each one in a `3k+1` position.

```
$ awk -F";" '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i+=3) sum+=$i} END{print sum}' file
159
```

The value is printed after processing the whole file, in the `END {}` block.

Comment: And what about if my input is:
a;b;2;c;d
3;e;3;s;g
h;5;2;d;d

The problem is the same: sum every 3th number in each row.
Outpus should looks:
7

Comment: @csib it is not clear what you mean. Update your question with this information, together with what you try and what is your desired output.

Comment: @csib for this you can do `awk -F";" '{sum+=$3} END{print sum}' file`. It is the same logic, only that instead of looping through all the fields, we directly access to the 3rd with `$3`.